# How do I change the video src when I click on a link using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

How can I make it so that when I click on a link it changes the src of a video using jQuery,

So if the user clicks "#staff" it will change the video src

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" >
            <li role="presentation" class="loginPills"><a id="student" href="#">Student  </a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="loginPills"><a id="staff" href="#">Staff</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="loginPills"><a id="employer"href="#">Employer</a></li>
        </ul>
```

My video

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="" id="bgvid">
<source src="Border-Collies.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="mp4">
```

My code (not working)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#staff').on({
    'click': function(){
        $('#mp4').attr('src','The-Coast.mp4');
        $('#webm').attr('src','The-Coast.webm');
        console.log("click");
    }
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine but as per the specs, dynamically changing src attribute does not work.

Read https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-source-element.html

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the
>   element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no
>   effect.

Comment: Is there anyway around this?

Comment: @Aueisbiejei3i939 specs does talk about this https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype. go through it once.

Comment: @Aueisbiejei3i939 I posted a way.

Answer (score 1):

You need only to change the attribute of the video tag not the source tag as follows:

Replace

```
$('#mp4').attr('src','The-Coast.mp4');
```

with

`$('#bgvid').attr('src','The-Coast.mp4')`;

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `src` of a `source` tag dynamically, you need to call `.load()` on the video after.

Here's a demo.

```js
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('source').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
  document.getElementById('video').load();
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="change">click</a>

<video controls id="video">
  <source src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" id="source">
</video>
```